# Breadcrumb with MVC Sitemap shows only one level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I need to use MVCSitemap provider in a web application, but I can't make it work where I have dynamic urls.

I have a list of categories, which can have parents and children.
For example if I click on a category, the breadcrumb looks like this:

```
Home > Filter
```

if I click on a children of the Filter, I got:

```
Filter > Air filter
```

the Home link disappears.
If I click on the childrens of the "Air filter" I got:

```
Air filter > air filter children
```

and so on. Always the two last levels are showed, and if I click on the first level, always goes back to the Home page.

This is in my MvcSitemap:

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Product" controller="Product" action="SubCategories" preservedRouteParameters="selected,category,id,engineId">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Product" action="ProductDetails" preservedRouteParameters="supplierName,code,name,prodId,-1"/>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>

  </mvcSiteMapNode>
```

This is the Subcategories method from Product controller:

```
 [MvcSiteMapNode(Title = "Article", ParentKey = "SubCategories")]
 [Route("{selected}-{category}-{id}-{engineId}")]
 public ActionResult SubCategories(string selected, string category, int id, string engineId)
    {  
         ...........................  
        SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.Title = categoryName;
        if(categoryRepository.GetCategoryByID(id).ParentId.HasValue)
        {
            int parentId = categoryRepository.GetCategoryByID(id).ParentId.Value;
            string parentName = categoryRepository.GetCategoryByID(parentId).Name;
            SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.ParentNode.RouteValues["id"] = id;
            SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode.ParentNode.Title = parentName;
        }
```

Can you please help me, what I'm doing wrong here?
I checked all the explanations on the web, I tried in many ways, but none of them resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my sample. You can refer it.

The first, I have a sitemap:

```
 <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="About" controller="Home" action="About" />
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Contact" controller="Home" action="Contact" />
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Administration" clickable="false">
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="User Mgmt" controller="Administration" action="UserMgmt" clickable="false" >
            <mvcSiteMapNode title="List Role" controller="Administration" action="ListRole" >
              <mvcSiteMapNode title="Details" controller="Administration" action="Details">
                <mvcSiteMapNode title="XXX" controller="Administration" action="XXX" />
              </mvcSiteMapNode>
            </mvcSiteMapNode>
          </mvcSiteMapNode>
          <mvcSiteMapNode title="Role Mgmt" controller="Home" action="RoleMgmt" />    
        </mvcSiteMapNode>    
      </mvcSiteMapNode>

//And then, I create a BootstrapMenuHelperModel view that load this sitemap. //I putted it at DisplayTemplates. 

@model MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models.MenuHelperModel
@using MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.Models

@helper  TopMenu(List<SiteMapNodeModel> nodeList)
{
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    @foreach (SiteMapNodeModel node in nodeList)
                    {
                        string url = node.IsClickable ? node.Url : "#";

                        if (!node.Children.Any())
                        {
                            <li><a href="@url">@node.Title</a></li>
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">@node.Title <span class="caret"></span></a>
                                @DropDownMenu(node.Children)
                            </li>
                        }

                        if (node != nodeList.Last())
                        {
                            <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        }
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
}

@helper DropDownMenu(SiteMapNodeModelList nodeList)
{
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        @foreach (SiteMapNodeModel node in nodeList)
        {
            if (node.Title == "Separator")
            {
                <li class="divider"></li>
                continue;
            }

            string url = node.IsClickable ? node.Url : "#";

            if (!node.Children.Any())
            {
                <li><a href="@url">@node.Title</a></li>
            }
            else
            {
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="@url">@node.Title</a>@DropDownMenu(node.Children)</li>
            }
        }
    </ul>
}

@TopMenu(Model.Nodes)

//Finally, call this view from layout
<div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <nav>
                    @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu("BootstrapMenuHelperModel")
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. This is not exactly what I was looking for, but I will try to use it in my example.